# How to rotate a 3D object in SketchUp?

Tags: cad, sketchup

I'm trying to create something that looks like a large touch screen, which I intend to angle at 45° to the floor. I.e. imagine how you might arrange this touch screen so that it's at a comfortable angle for people to operate at a trade show.

I'm really struggling to understand how to rotate my object correctly. Here is my object lying on the floor (I've labelled the corners to make my description clearer):

[image: object on floor]

I tried to rotate by clicking on the **D** corner, then dragging the mouse towards **C** to define my axis of rotation. But then I'm not really clear where else I should click to get my rotation working correctly. What tends to happen is the following:

[image: the problem]

Can someone explain how to rotate this shape correctly?

Comment: Try selecting the entire object first.  If you don't have luck rotating it, create a box, add the diagonals, and create the rectangle at 45 degrees.  Then delete the unneeded part of the structure and pull the face for the thickness.

Comment: @fixer1234 Bingo, that did it. Do you want to write a brief answer to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Select the entire object, then rotate.
2. Create the object at the angle you want (I find it easier to do it this way).  Create the 3D box that will contain the back of the angled object.  Draw in the diagonals on both sides to create the diagonal slice.  Delete the unneeded parts of the box, leaving the diagonal slice.  Then pull the face to get the thickness.